# Manjaro Sway monitor screen through DisplayLink not working

Tags: manjaro, multi-monitor, wayland, sway, displaylink

I am trying to have my Lenovo DisplayLink to work with Manjaro Sway but so far could not manage to have screen signal going through it.

I updated my linux to kernel 5.15
I installed the corresponding linux-headers to properly install evdi
I installed displayconnect

When I run

`systemctl start displaylink.service`

It crashes

When I log back in a shell without and start sway manually it gives the following error:

```
00:00:00.032 [ERROR] [wlr] [EGL] command: eglQueryDeviceStringEXT, error: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER (0x300c), message: "eglQueryDeviceStringEXT"
00:00:00.032 [ERROR] [wlr] [EGL] command: eglQueryDeviceStringEXT, error: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER (0x300c), message: "eglQueryDeviceStringEXT"
MESA-LOADER: failed to open evdi: /usr/lib/dri/evdi_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
failed to load driver: evdi
kmsro: driver missing
MESA-LOADER: failed to open evdi: /usr/lib/dri/evdi_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
failed to load driver: evdi
kmsro: driver missing
00:00:00.067 [ERROR] [wlr] [render/egl.c:424] Failed to get DRM device: No such device
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
MESA-LOADER: failed to open evdi: /usr/lib/dri/evdi_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
failed to load driver: evdi
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
kmsro: driver missing
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
MESA-LOADER: failed to open evdi: /usr/lib/dri/evdi_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
failed to load driver: evdi
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
kmsro: driver missing
2022-09-16 14:02:33 - [swaybg-1.1.1/main.c:579] Missing a required Wayland interface
```

Any help would be greetly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the evdi module package might have been corrupt. If you installed it from the Manjaro repo, you can try the AUR version and the corresponding DisplayLink package version. Just check if the evdi version you are installing is compatible with the kernel. If it won't work with mainline kernel, you can try the LTS version.

As a last resort you can try it with other DE like Gnome with Wayland, in general on Wayland it should work without any extra configuration. On X some extra configuration is needed, depending on the distro.